# How to deal with questions where the answer only works in parts of the world?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Reading the question and answers to "[Type of switch for AC power cord?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/143565/type-of-switch-for-ac-power-cord)" my immedeate thought was "no, bad idea" but at least one answer suggests that an spst is ok.

Now looking at the OP info, the country suggests that plugs are polarized there, and this answer would be ok for him, but correct me if I am wrong, but the site is supposed to be international.

There are many countries where using an spst is often a bad idea (though there you can even buy approved appliances that don't use dpst) due to plugs not being polarized.

Especially for future visitors that are not skilled enough to answer the question and the why for themselves, it seems somewhat dangerous to leave such questions the way they are. There are many more questions and answers that talk about things like possible code violations etc. that do only apply to a specific country.

Would it be more appropriate to mark those answers (or questions too) with some big "automatic" (that is with UI support and automated boilerplate text) disclaimer "This question/answer is about safety. It applies only to the following countries: " ?

Answer (score 3):

Safety concerns should be raised in comments or answers to the question, and that seems to have occurred more than adequately in this particular case.

And your safety concerns might be a bit overblown in any case. The type of switch used does not play a part in an appliance's mains isolation scheme. After all, when the switch is on, there's no isolation at all! An intact appliance will have suitable barriers between the user and direct mains contact (e.g., double insulation), and an appliance that has been opened up for servicing should be unplugged, not merely switched off.

Comment: I see where you are coming from, but unfortunately not everyone goes to the breaker box or unplugs stuff from the outlet behind the couch to change a light bulb... They just use the devices switch.